# C Preprocessing with Python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

I've never used regular expressions before and I'm struggling to make sense of them. I have strings in the form of `'define(__arch64__)'` and I just want the `__arch64__`.

```
import re  
mystring = 'define(this_symbol)||define(that_symbol)'  
pattern = 'define\(([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\)'  
re.search(mystring, pattern).groups()
```

> (None, None)

What doesn't `search` return `'this_symbol'` and `'that_symbol'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the parameters of [`search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) in the wrong order, it should be:

```
re.search(pattern, mystring)
```

Also, backslashes are escape characters in python strings (for example "\n" will be a string containing a newline). If you want literal backslaches, like in the regular expression, you have to escape them with another backslash. Alternatively you can use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) that are marked by an `r` in front of them and don't treat backslashes as escape characters:

```
pattern = r'define\(([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\)'
```

Comment: That fixed it. Adding the r didn't seem to make any difference though.

Comment: @Neil: Probably because `\(`, `\)` and `\w` aren't valid escape sequences in Python strings, so they didn't get replaced by anything else. But generally I'd recommend to use the `r` when dealing with strings that should contain backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

You must differentiate between the symbol `(` and the regexp group characters. Also, the pattern goes first in [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search):

```
pattern = 'define\\(([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\\)'
re.search(pattern, mystring).groups()
```